# Most efficient way in Go to stream io.ReadCloser to a file?

Tags: go

Given an io.ReadCloser, from the response of an HTTP request for example, what is the most efficient way both in memory overhead and code readability to stream the response to a File?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use [`io.Copy`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy)?

Comment: I actually didn't find it at first. Interfaces in Go make it tricky to know you what types implement which interfaces. With `Copy(dst Writer, src Reader)`  it's not immediately clear that io.ReadCloser and File implement Reader and Writer.

Comment: You should read about some of the [naming conventions](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface-names) in Go, it should be very clear that `io.ReadCloser` implements `Reader` (and `Closer`). I guess `File` takes a small amount of digging, but one would kinda expect you could read and write to Files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[io.Copy](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) is undoubtedly the most efficient in terms of code; you only need to

```
outFile, err := os.Create(filename)
// handle err
defer outFile.Close()
_, err = io.Copy(outFile, res.Body)
// handle err
```

it's also likely to be pretty efficient in terms of CPU and memory as well. You can peek at the [implementation of io.Copy](http://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=12247:12307#L340) if you want; assuming that the body doesn't implement `WriteTo` and the file doesn't implement `ReadFrom` (a quick glance says that they don't), `Copy` will copy chunks of up to 32kB at a time. A bigger chunk would probably use a bit less CPU but more memory; the value they picked seems like a good tradeoff.

Comment: Speaking of buffer size, go1.5 will have an `io.CopyBuffer`, which allows you to pass in the buffer to use for the Copy operation

Comment: @JimB ah very nice :)

Comment: In Go 1.15 and later, the call to io.Copy in the answer calls `outfile.ReadFrom(res.Body)` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `File.ReadFrom`:

```
package main

import (
   "net/http"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   r, e := http.Get("https://stackoverflow.com")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   f, e := os.Create("index.html")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   f.ReadFrom(r.Body)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/os#File.ReadFrom